# How to set required (to true) on a select from ManytoOne relationship?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

When I check the  Symfony Doc, I see that I can set required to true only on choice type or collection type.

***EventsType:***

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('nameEvent')
        ->add('nameOrga')
        ->add('Job')
        ->add('description')
        ->add('typeEvents')
        ->add('genreEvents')
    ;
}
```

***Events.php:***

```
class Events
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TypeEvents", inversedBy="events", cascade={"persist"})
     *
     */
    private $typeEvents;

    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="GenreEvents", inversedBy="events", cascade={"persist"})
     *
     */
    private $genreEvents;

    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BISSAP\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="events", cascade={"persist"})
     *
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="NameEvent", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nameEvent;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="NameOrga", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nameOrga;
```

So, how can I set required to true on the typeEvents and genreEvents ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a `JoinColumn` for these associations, and then to make these `JoinColumns` not NULLable using `"nullable"=false`.

Check out more about JoinColumns: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-one-unidirectional